# What does Spring use to do deserialization?

Tags: spring, kotlin, jackson, spring-webflux

I have the following class:

```
data class Thing(val lines: List<String>)
```

The JSON representation is:

```
{
    "lines": [
        "something",
        "something else"
    ]
}
```

Spring WebFlux can successfully parse this with the following:

```
// Parse the JSON as an object and return it.
request -> ServerResponse.ok().body(request.bodyToMono(Thing::class.java)
```

However, using Jackson directly with either of the following techniques fails:

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper()
val item = mapper.readValue<Thing>("""{"lines":["something","something else"]}""")
```

```
ServerResponse.ok().body(request.bodyToMono(Map::class.java)
        .map { map ->
            val mapper = ObjectMapper()
            val tmp = mapper.convertValue(map, Thing::class.java)
        }
```

The error is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `Thing` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

I thought that Spring was using Jackson to do its transformation. And I thought that Jackson could cope with such basic transformations from JSON -> POJOs. Using a `@JsonDeserialize` class obviously works. So why does the first example work and the second not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring uses Jackson but it registers custom handlers and modules when it creates its default instance of ObjectMapper.

Jackson has special handling for constructors that take a single argument. This was done to support classes like UUID and URI. To instruct Jackson to not use this technique, annotate your constructor with @JsonCreator.

```
data class Thing @JsonCreator constructor(val lines: List<String>)
```

I have not reviewed Spring's reactive code so I do not know what or if it does something to disable Jackson's special handling.

Comment: What does this special handling consist of? What can it be used for? And why does `bodyToMono` ignore this behaviour?

Comment: if i remember correctly this legacy reason was that you can pass in a full json object as a string in the first constructor parameter and then deserialize it from just that alone. And that this was done to support old classes and old databases. They are discussing about removing this in jackson 3.x https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1498